# How to use a remote shell on a machine outside of network

Tags: routing, router, ip, ip-address

I understand the differences between LAN and WAN addresses. My question is: while outside a network, how do you target a specific machine's address beneath a public IP?

Since a public IP for each machine on a given network will be the same, how does one find the specific DNS address on a particular network?

Example: Using Mac OS, I could very easily ssh into a machine using their specific internal IP (i.e. 192.168.0.100). What is the equivalent as an outsider?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: Done /x1f/x00/x00/x00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> while outside a network, how do you target a specific machine's address beneath a public IP?

You can't. The private IP address only makes sense *within* its local scope. From without, the private IP address is useless.

There are ways to work around this though. One is to translate from a public address to a private address (most often in connection with a transport layer port), known as destination NAT, port forwarding, virtual host, virtual IP, ...

The other is to directly connect to the local scope using some kind of tunneling - VPN, PPTP, SSH, ...